# Could not find class [io.awspring.cloud.jdbc.config.annotation.AmazonRdsInstanceConfiguration] while using spring-cloud-starter-aws

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-aws, aws-sqs-fifo, sqslistener

I'm using spring boot 2.5.3 version and trying to listen aws sqs messages through @SqsListener
i'm able to send message to queue but not able to listen to it
added these dependencies

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.620</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sts</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.620</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-messaging</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

with these application is running fine but not able to listen to queues
so i added started dependency post which i was getting mentioned error:localizedMessage":"Could not find class [io.awspring.cloud.jdbc.config.annotation.AmazonRdsInstanceConfiguration]","message":"Could not find class [io.awspring.cloud.jdbc.config.annotation.AmazonRdsInstanceConfiguration]","name":"java.lang.IllegalArgumentException","cause":{"commonElementCount":93,"localizedMessage":"io.awspring.cloud.jdbc.config.annotation.AmazonRdsInstanceConfiguration"

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

the same application is running fine and able to listen to messages in spring boot version 2.4.3

I have tried with different versions of aws starter and failed to get a solution